# Segmentation Fault sysfs gpio linux odroid

Tags: linux, bash, linux-device-driver, gpio, sysfs

I'm trying to write a script that outputs to a GPIO pin for 1 second.
I found that the best way to do this is through the GPIO sysfs commands, but I keep getting "Segmentation Fault" randomly. This happens mainly when setting direction. This also happens when running in a bash script and through the terminal.

```
sudo echo 227 > /sys/class/gpio/export
sudo chmod 777 /sys/class/gpio/gpio227/*
sudo echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio227/direction # sometimes segmentation fault
sudo echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio227/value
# wait a bit
sudo echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio227/direction # almost always segmentation fault
sudo echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio227/value
```

I'm running this on a ODROID-XU4 with Ubuntu MATE 1.12.1 and with ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l). I am also running passwordless sudo.

Any suggestions on why this happens and how to prevent it?

EDIT: I thought I was originally running on an ODROID-XU3 but it's actually an XU4.

Comment: What the heck is this `sudo chmod 777 /sys/class/gpio/gpio227/*` for?! Besides that read documentation how to communicate with GPIO subsystem in user space, in particular use **low** and **high** instead of separate commands. And on top of that, do you know exactly what you are doing when switching this GPIO as is?

Comment: The `chmod 777` is to enable write access for the gpio227 files since they don't start with it to begin with.  Without it, I get a permissions error when running any echos into direction or value.  I didn't have to use `777`, but it was just quicker. I'll try just running **low** and **high** and see if that works.

Comment: It seems like your gpio 227 is not exported to configure it as GPO, That is why you do not have a write permission. Check the significance of the hardware pins before you try to override it's property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing some other ways of setting the GPIO values, I've found that other frameworks seem to have worked fine without segmentation faults.

In conclusion, using echo to write to the GPIO pin was the source of the segmentation fault. I do not know why though.

My work around was to either use the gpio module from node or use wiringPi for Odroid since those seemed to have worked just fine.

Posting this so people know.

Answer (score 1):

Segmentation fault usually occurs when a user space program reads or writes an illegal memory address. It is not common that this happens with a simple and well-tested program such as echo.

It could be caused by the kernel/GPIO driver which is buggy or maybe even broken hardware. I would suggest to run the command directly as root to make sure it is echo which is causing segmentation faults and then use strace to figure out if the segmentation fault happens always at the same location...